# Duplicate rows in a value range of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
   A.low  A.up  B  C
0  1      3     1  D 
1  1      2     2  E
2  2      4     1  E
```

how can I duplicate the rows in the range of the indexes A.low and A.up. The steps are integers. So my desired output would be:

```
   A.low  A.up  B  C  A
0  1      3     1  D  1
1  1      3     1  D  2
2  1      3     1  D  3
3  1      2     2  E  1
4  1      2     2  E  2
5  2      4     1  E  2
6  2      4     1  E  3
7  2      4     1  E  4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) first, then create new column `A` by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with `A.low` and last create default `RangeIndex`:

```
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['A.up'] - df['A.low'] + 1)]
df['A'] = df.groupby(level=0).cumcount() + df['A.low']
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   A.low  A.up  B  C  A
0      1     3  1  D  1
1      1     3  1  D  2
2      1     3  1  D  3
3      1     2  2  E  1
4      1     2  2  E  2
5      2     4  1  E  2
6      2     4  1  E  3
7      2     4  1  E  4
```